# SQL command two merge

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL.

I am having table as below:

```
EMP_NUMBER ATTDATE     ATTTIME
00001      01-05-2018   9:00
00001      01-05-2018   18:00
00001      02-05-2018   8:00
00001      02-05-2018   20:00
```

Now I want SQL query use above table date to create the table as below format:

```
EMP_NUMBER   ATTDATE      ATTINTIME    ATTOUTTIME
00001        01-05-2018    9:00         18:00
00001        02-05-2018    8:00          20:00
```

Comment: Is it MSSQL or mySql? which Software you use for Database management?

Comment: mysql .. i need mysql query to acieve this.

Comment: Do u want to create a new column named as ATTOUTTIME or just view as output?

Comment: ATTOUTTIME column should be created. I need output in table..

Comment: You could save yourself a world of pain by storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: @Strawberry Feel the burn, baby!  Watch the green points in your inbox :-)

Answer (score 2):

A simple `GROUP BY` query should work here:

```
SELECT
    EMP_NUMBER,
    ATTDATE,
    MIN(ATTTIME) AS ATTINTIME,
    MAX(ATTTIME) AS ATTOUTTIME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EMP_NUMBER,
    ATTDATE;
```

Note: This answer assumes that your date and time information are in actual `datetime` and `time` columns.  If not, then you're working directly with text, and it won't sort properly.  As a temporary remedy, you may use `STR_TO_DATE`.  For example, you may convert the `ATTTIME` column to proper time using this:

```
STR_TO_DATE(ATTTIME, '%H:%i')
```